# React and Gsap Animation Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap

So I am trying to animate my react app using Gsap I am trying to create a animation using scroll trigger
When the section comes into view the heading should move.

I am rendering a list from data that I have.

Issue: The heading moves for first section but if I delay the scroll it wont move for other sections.
Means it only moves for first section.

I have tried using gsap useEffect Method it didn't worked and also used Tween Component Method still didn't worked.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { homeData } from "./homedata";
import classes from "./MainContainer.module.css";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { Tween } from "react-gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger";
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const MainContainer = () => {
  const boxRef = useRef(homeData.map(() => React.createRef()));

  useEffect(() => {
    // boxRef.current.forEach((ref, index) => {
    // gsap.fromTo(
    //   ref.current,
    //   { y: 0 },
    //   {
    //     y: -100,
    //     duration: 2,
    //     ease: "bounce",
    //     scrollTrigger: {
    //       id: `section-${index}`,
    //       trigger: boxRef.current[index].current,
    //       start: "top center+=100",
    //     },
    //   }
    // );
    // console.log(ScrollTrigger);
    // });
    // ScrollTrigger.create({
    //   trigger: boxRef.current[2].current,
    //   onEnter: () => {
    //     console.log("Happened");
    //   },
    //   // onLeave: myLeaveFunc,
    //   // onEnterBack: myEnterFunc,
    //   // onLeaveBack: myLeaveFunc,
    // });
    // console.log(boxRef.current[0].current.focus);
    // //
    // gsap.to(boxRef.current[2].current, {
    //   y: -100,
    //   duration: 2,
    //   ease: "bounce",
    //   delay: 1,
    //   scrollTrigger: boxRef.current[2].current,
    // });
  }, []);

  console.log(boxRef);
  return (
    <section>
      {homeData.map((location, index) => {
        return (
          <section
            id={`section-${index}`}
            key={index}
            className={classes["home-section"]}
            style={{ background: `url(${location.image}) center/cover` }}
          >
            <div className={classes["left-side-main"]}>
              <Tween
                to={{
                  x: "300px",

                  scrollTrigger: {
                    trigger: `#heading${index}`,
                  },
                }}
              >
                <h1 ref={boxRef.current[index]} id={`heading${index}`}>
                  {location.location}
                </h1>
              </Tween>
              <div className={classes["previous-next"]}>
                <button>Previous</button>
                <span></span>
                <button>Next</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={classes["right-side-main"]}>
              <p>{location.description}</p>
              <div className={classes["images-right-side"]}>
                <img src={location.moreImages[0]} alt="" />
                <img src={location.moreImages[1]} alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        );
      })}
    </section>
  );
};

export default MainContainer;
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could create codesendbox or something like that with your code. That way it would be easier for use to see what is going on

Comment: Also, I don't believe that you are using useRef the proper way. What is looged in console.log

Comment: I have created codesand box https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-bartik-56jg9

Comment: It works there but not in localhost

Comment: I got it its due to smooth scrolling that I added could you please tell me the solution to it @LazarNikolic